# Adding QFileDialog as a widget inside another QDialog

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I'm attempting to create a dialog which contains two child widgets: on the left side a `QFileDialog` instance so users can select files, and on the right side a separate widget which will be used to show a preview of the selected file if it is of a certain type.

The problem is that the dialog opens up and I can see the "preview" widget just fine, but the `QFileDialog` is not showing up at all.

This short example demonstrates my problem:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

app = QApplication([])

main_dialog = QDialog()
main_dialog.setWindowTitle('My Dialog')
layout = QHBoxLayout(main_dialog)

file_dialog = QFileDialog(main_dialog, Qt.Widget)
file_dialog.setOption(QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
layout.addWidget(file_dialog)

preview = QLabel('Preview', main_dialog)
layout.addWidget(preview)

main_dialog.show()

app.exec_()
```

Some things that I've tried:

1. Add `file_dialog.show()` before/after `main_dialog.show()`: this shows up the `QFileDialog`, but in a different window; I want the file dialog to appear inside `main_dialog`, not as a separate window;
2. Do not pass `Qt.Widget` to the `QFileDialog` constructor, to no effect;
3. Do not pass `main_dialog` as parent to `QFileDialog`, again no effect;
4. Change `main_dialog` to a `QWidget` just to see if it changed anything, it did not;

I've searched the docs but did not find a suitable solution.

Any hints? Also, suggestions on how to accomplish the task of allowing the user to select a file and display a preview of the file in the same window are welcome.

**Context**: this is a port of an old application written for Qt3. Qt3's `QFileSystem` dialog had this "preview" functionality built-in; I'm trying to reproduce the same functionality in Qt5.

**Versions**

- Python 2.7
- PyQt 5.5.1

I've also tried with Python 3.6 (from conda-forge) but obtained the same behavior.

Comment: You have tried using the following code:`file_dialog = QFileDialog(None, Qt.Widget)`? To me it works, and another thing, which you mean with preview exactly.

Comment: You could display an image of what QFileSystem preview was showing.

Comment: Oddly, it is not possible to set the parent and flags at the same time. So `file_dialog = QFileDialog(main_dialog); file_dialog.setWindowFlags(Qt.Widget)`, will also work. You can also omit the parent altogether, since widgets are always automatically re-parented when they're added to a layout.

Comment: @ekhumoro I did not know that, thanks. This also explains why the answer marked as solution worked as well.

Comment: @BrunoOliveira. Yes, it's not necessary to remove `Qt.Dialog`. BTW, I think you are going to face a much bigger problem when it comes to generating previews. I would suggest looking for a third-party library.

Comment: @ekhumuro do you have a suggestion for a third party library?

Comment: @ eyllanesc I have to show a 2D grid colored by property value (using VTK) along with additional information such as number of points, grid dimensions, etc.

Comment: @BrunoOliveira. My previous comment assumed you wanted to preview a wide range of file-types, but that appears not to be the case. If you only need to handle one, quite specialised kind of file, the problem is much smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn off the [`Qt.Dialog`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) flag in the file dialog's `windowFlags`...

```
file_dialog.setWindowFlags(file_dialog.windowFlags() & ~Qt.Dialog)
```

Otherwise the `QFileDialog` will always be created as a top level window.  Works for me anyway.

Comment: That indeed works! I thought passing `Qt.Widget` to the constructor would override it, it did not occur to me to have to unset the `Qt.Dialog` bit. Thanks a lot!